# Unable to lazily load JPA relationships

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm working with Jhipster. I'm not being able to fetch Customers lazily.

I have made a JDL like so...

```
 PROPERTY
 id
 ...

 CUSTOMER
 id
 ...

 CUSTOMER_PROPERTY
 id
 customer_id
 property_id
 value

 relationship OneToMany {
    Customer to CustomerProperty                    
 }
 relationship ManyToOne {
    CustomerProperty to Property    
 }
```

My Domains

Customer.java

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 private Set<CustomerProperty> customerProperties = new HashSet<>();
```

Property.java
     no mapping

CustomerProperty.java

```
 @ManyToOne
 private Property property;

 @ManyToOne
 @JsonIgnoreProperties("customerProperties")
 private Customer customer;
```

I have already tried to explicit set fetch = FetchType.LAZY but it keeps bringing the full complete Customer object with all CustomerProperties List

I would like to understand why the fetch it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging is not a good mechanism for evaluation if a collection has been lazily loaded or not. The debugger itself may trigger initialization.

Instead of using debugger use the

```
org.hibernate.Hibernate.isInitialized(yourCollection)
```

to verify if it has been initialized after the loading of your entity.

If this method return false but you still suspect that at later point the collection is initialize you should search the error in a possible subsequent call (somewhere else).

Comment: Why the relation is being fetch even when i run the app the first time?

Comment: It is not fetched obviously after your repositry call. Either you are fetcihing it during debugging, or something else is fetching it at later point.

Comment: I still don't understand how you draw conclusion that it has been fetched. If you are drawing this conclusion based on your debugger that is 100% wrong I already told you why. If you have other reasons to think so then specify them. Your debugger is not a good reason.

Comment: OMG, I found out the problem(or maybe I should say you helped me a lot). You will desire to kill me :) it's the mapper class which invokes the getCustomerProperties which in turns calls getProperty and so on... but now I know next time I will use Hibernate.isInitialized(collection). Very appreciated mate. Keep up the good work!!!